# Using Python in the Field Calculator to select more than one data point

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, field-calculator, select-by-attribute, python-parser

I assume this is a basic Python coding question, but I have scoured the internet and spent several hours trying on my own. I have about 2000 cells in my FID_1_1 column that I need to select and code as "1" in another attribute column (exp100mWA). I have figured out how to do this with Python for 1 cell (27), but can't figure out how to do it for all of them. I have the list of numbers, but it doesn't like any way I try to code it, commas, spaces, ampersands, etc. Here's my field calculator box.

[image]

Comment: Could you provide a simplified example of what you are trying to accomplish? A screenshot from a spreadsheet will even be sufficient.

Comment: Please always include code as text rather than pictures of code.  There is an [edit] button beneath your question which will enable you to do that and a **`{}`** button that enables you to format any highlighted code nicely.  That way your code is available to future searches and can be copy/pasted for testing.

Comment: What's in your list? I think that you will need to do a join at some stage to resolve your list to features or compile your list like [27,next,next] and use in operator like if (FID_1_1 in [27,28,50]): (for example) for values 27, 28 and 50; it depends how long your list is, and personal preference, as to what's the best approach.

Answer (score 4):

This will depend on how big your list of records is - if it's very long it may be unmanageable to list them out.

```py
def myCalc(myfid, mylist):
    if myfid in mylist:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0
```

And the expression:

```py
myCalc(!FID_1_1!, [27, 50, 77, 103])
```

Which will return a `1` in the `exp100mWA` column if the value in `FID_1_1` is in the list - in my example the list is `27, 50, 77, 103`, so if the value in `FID_1_1` is any of those values, it will return `1`, otherwise `0`.

Comment: As a 'cherry on top' you could populate the list using a search cursor and call the list as a global in myCalc. As stated if it's a long list you wouldn't like to populate it manually - both tedious and possible typos. Note that python lists can be *very* long, up to the amount of addressable memory (4GiB as ArcGis is a 32bit process) minus the amount currently utilized.

Comment: @Laura If this answer has worked for you please consider upvoting and marking as the answer.  See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2):

Even though @Midavalo's answer to this question is the most concise (clearer) way of doing this, an alternative to this would be using a one-liner, again by using Python parser (without populating the code block, straight into the expression):

`{True:1,False:0}[!FID_1_1! in [27, 50, 77, 103]]`

I should admit though, the one-liners can be confusing for learners and does not reflect the same structure as `creating a function` and `calling it with its arguments` (essentially what you are trying to do as stated in your questions and what @Midavalo suggests). The arguments to the `def` that you want to use are there in an **implied** way.

This is the same as writing a code block like:

```
def some_def(sought_value,search_list):        
    what_I_want_to_return_after_truth_check = {True : 1, False : 0}
    if_my_value_is_in_the_search_list = sought_value in search_list
    return what_I_want_to_return_after_truth_check [if_my_value_is_in_the_search_list]
```

Comment: Can we see this in context of def myCalc(myfid, mylist)? An explanation of how this expands would help too.. One liners can be very confusing for learners; even some more experienced persons (myself included) find some *one line operations* cryptic.

Comment: [0,1][ !FID_1_1! in (27,50,77,103)] will do as well